# Incompatible types. Found 'char', required: 'T'

Tags: java, huffman-code

`EDIT: As pointed out by dratenik, this was indeed a design error and it could have easily been solved by removing any instances of T from my class and replacing them with chars and Characters where needed. I was stubborn though, and wanted to find a way to make it work with generics, and dratenik ALSO pointed out how to solve it (by sending instances of T to the method instead of trying to use chars directly), so huge thanks to them!`

`I don't know how to close questions or flag them as solved, but consider it solved! The new code is as follows:`

```
public void fileDecoding(File oldFile, File newFile, PriorityQueue<T> pq) throws Exception{
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(oldFile));
    FileWriter fW = new FileWriter(newFile);
    if(newFile.canRead() && newFile.canWrite()) {
        root = new Node(null);
        convertCodeToTree(root, bis, pq);
        bis.read();
        decodeText(root, bis, fW);
    }
    else throw new Exception("No permissions to read and write to file");
    fW.close();
    bis.close();
}
private void convertCodeToTree(Node node, BufferedInputStream bis, PriorityQueue<T> pq) throws Exception{
        int readChar = bis.read();
        if(readChar != -1 && (char) readChar != '\n'){
            if(readChar == '0'){
                node.left = new Node(null);
                convertCodeToTree(node.left, bis, pq);
                node.right = new Node(null);
                convertCodeToTree(node.right, bis, pq);
            }
            if(readChar == '1'){
                for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) bis.read();
                node.data = pq.dequeue();
            }
        }
    }
```

`THIS HAS BEEN SOLVED, but it might help someone with the same problem as me, so I'm not erasing it.`

I have an assignment to create from scratch an implementation of the Huffman Coding, using classes and methods also made from scratch.

The whole compression part went by smoothly, but while trying to write the method to decompress the test file, I bumped into a really annoying problem. I tried to search google for ways to solve it and I couldn't find it, so I decided to write here. Pardon any mistakes, English isn't my first language.

(Also, quick edit, I removed T extends Character. That was a failed attempt at solving the problem and it didn't work)

```
public class HuffmanBST<T extends Comparable<T>>{
class Node{
    private T data;
    private Node left, right;
    Node(T data){
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
    Node(Node left, Node right){
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
public void readFromFile(File file) throws Exception{
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String treeBinary = br.readLine();
    int i = 0;
    convertCodeToTree(root, treeBinary, i);
    decodeText(root);
    bis.close();
}
private void convertCodeToTree(Node node, String firstline, int index){    
char data = firstline.charAt(index);
    if(data == 0) {
        node = new Node(null);
        convertCodeToTree(node.left, firstline, index++);
        convertCodeToTree(node.right, firstline, index++);
    }
    if(data == 1){
        String binaryToString = "";
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 8){
            index++;
            binaryToString += firstline.charAt(index);
            i++;
        }
        char stringToChar = (char) Integer.parseInt(binaryToString, 2);
        node = new Node(stringToChar); // This gives a compile-time error
    }
}
```

This is the method I was writing to rebuild the Huffman tree from an already compressed text file, but it gives me a compile-time error:

`'Node(T)' in 'HuffmanBST.Node' cannot be applied to '(char)'`

I assume it's because my HuffmanBST class takes a generic T and assigns it to the data value of the Node and now the node doesn't want to be created because it can't know for sure what T is until runtime. But I have another method which basically does the same thing, but there it works no problem and no errors.

```
public void buildTree(PriorityQueue<T> frequencies){
    PriorityQueue<Node> huffmanPQ = new PriorityQueue<>();
    while(!frequencies.isEmpty()) huffmanPQ.enqueue(frequencies.getPriority(),
            new Node(frequencies.dequeue())); // Doesn't throw a compile-time error.
    while(huffmanPQ.size() > 1){
        int weight1 = huffmanPQ.getPriority(); Node n1 = huffmanPQ.dequeue();
        int weight2 = huffmanPQ.getPriority(); Node n2 = huffmanPQ.dequeue();
        Node newNode = new Node(n1, n2);
        huffmanPQ.enqueue((weight1+weight2), newNode);
    }
    root = huffmanPQ.dequeue();
}
```

So what am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What s the point to have a type parameter that extends Character?

Comment: To extend on @vincendep comment: [class `Character` is `final`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html) and thus cannot be subclassed.

Comment: You need a `T`, all you have is a `char`. There may be a design error somewhere. Does it make sense for the thing to be generic and agnostic about `T`?

Comment: @dratenik I am not entirely sure this is the issue (see [this Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/XvjUAT) which - given your line of argumentation - should not work). I am, however, not entirely sure what the difference between the demo and the code provided is. Normally, auto(un)boxing should kick in.

Comment: If you really want to HuffmanBST to be agnostic about T, the caller of convertCodeToTree (/readFromFile) may need to supply an external thing that converts pieces of text to instances of T? (HuffmanBST doesn't know what specific type T is and how to construct it, the caller might)

Comment: `I don't know how to close questions or flag them as solved` - post an answer to your own question and then flag it has the solution.